# Adding item in combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, datatable

I want to add a item to `combobox` which already in bounded with some data.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub showSection()
        sb = New StringBuilder()
        sb.Remove(0, sb.Length)
        sb.Append("SELECT DISTINCT Section ")
        sb.Append(" FROM Employee ")
        sb.Append(" ORDER BY Section")
        Dim sqlSection As String = sb.ToString()

        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlSection, Conn)
        da.Fill(ds, "Section")

        dt = ds.Tables("Section")
        bs.DataSource = dt

        With cbSection
            .DisplayMember = "Section"
            .ValueMember = "Section"
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("Section")
            .DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bs, "Section")
        End With
End Sub
```

But I want add item, like `"---All---"`, so this is should be the output.

```
---All---
HR
Store
Packing
Training
Qc
Qa
Stock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simple solution

```
Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
dr("Section") = "---All---"
dr("SectionId") = 0
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)

With cbSection
    .DisplayMember = "Section"
    .ValueMember = "SectionId"
    .DataSource = ds.Tables("Section")
    .DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bs, "Section")
End With

cbSection.SelectedIndex = 0
```